# Azure Active Directory and Windows Authentication

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, azure-active-directory

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5. and trying to find out if it's possible to authenticate against Azure Active Directory with a web app using windows authentication instead of organizational authentication? I don't need a separate sign on page or registration, so rather than send them to an azure login page I would like to just bring up the browser prompt to athenticate.

It appears that the organizational authentication option relies on the reply url from the azure login page. Windows authentication works against a windows active directory but wondering if anyone has ever successfully used it against AAD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Windows authentication depends on [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) (or NTLM), which needs an Active Directory domain to authenticate the user in. Azure Active Directory does not handle Kerberos tokens.

You can have your users authenticate against [ADFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services) using the Kerberos protocol and federate the security token in [ACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_Service).

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like the alternative ADFS would have to be done outside of Azure then or migrated to a VM.

Comment: Right, your ADFS would issue security tokens for your on-prem Active Directory and would also live inside your domain. It would use a protocol like WS-Federation to exchange tokens with ACS.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your AAD tenant is federated with your onpremises AD and your user is accessing from within the corporate network, where Windows auth works, you can absolutely do that. You can skip the interstitial page by simply specifying in advance the domain of your tenant. See http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

Comment: Tenant federated as in synced with the onprem AD?

Comment: Both, unless you want to be in the business of keeping your on-prem AD and your AAD directory in sync (trust me, you don't). Setting up federation is configuring AAD to hand off authentication to your on-prem AD FS, but it still needs to match a valid user in AAD.